# Maximum of $\ell^2$-Norm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For $r,c>0$ put
$$X_{c,r}=\{x \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \mid  \|x\|_1=r, \, \forall i\in \mathbb{N}: |x_i|<c\}.$$
Then I can show that $\inf_{x \in X_{c, r}} \|x\|_2=0$.
Is it possible to compute
$$s_c:=\sup_{x \in X_{c,r}} \|x\|_2 \quad ?$$
Does at least $\lim_{c \to 0} s_c=0$ hold?

Comment: I think that if $r\leq c$ then $s_c=r$.  If $r>c$, then let $n=\mathrm{floor}(r/c)$ and $a = r- cn$.  I think $s_c= \sqrt{n c^2 + a^2}$.

Comment: Con you solve the equivalent problem for finite sequences, i.e. if $|x_1|+|x_2|+\dots |x_n|=r$ and $|x_i|\leq c$ for all $i\in \{1, \dots, n\}$ then what is the maximum value of $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+\dots + |x_n|^2$?

Answer (score 1):

For you very last question, notice that if $x\in X_{c, t}$,
$$\|x\|^2_2=\sum_nx^2_n<c\sum_n|x_n|=c\|x\|_1=cr$$
Thus $s_{c, r}\leq \sqrt{cr}\xrightarrow{c\rightarrow0}0$.